# The 100 Game - Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Computer Science and to Stack Overflow and I'm currently stuck with this IGCSE summer work. I'm creating a game called "100" in Python and the rule is whoever reaches 100 first wins. The coding's below:

```
# Exercise 4 - Beginner
while True:
    print("~~~~~ THE 100 GAME - CODED BY SASU ~~~~~")
    print('----- MENU -----')
    print('1 - Start multiplayer game')
    print('2 - Quit game')
    choice = int(input('What are you going to do? Input the number representing your choice.'))
    if choice == 1:
        print('Let's do it!')
    elif choice == 2:
        print('See you soon.')
        break  # In order to stop the program and quit
    else:
        print('What the heck? Type again.')
        print("~~~~~ THE 100 GAME - CODED BY SASU ~~~~~")
        print('----- MENU -----')
        print('1 - Start multiplayer game')
        print('2 - Quit game')
        choice = int(input('What are you going to do? Input the number representing your choice.'))
        if choice == 1:
            print('Let's do it!')
        elif choice == 2:
            print('See you soon.')
            break  # In order to stop the program and quit
        else:
            print('What the heck? Type again.')  # After this it just starts the multiplayer game right away I don't know how to fix this
    while True:
        print('Yooo player 1, tell me your name:')
        oneName = input()
        print('Well then, player 2, what about ya?')
        twoName = input()
        print('Well hey there, ' + oneName + ' and ' + twoName + ', and welcome to 100!')
        print('You will each take turns to choose a number between 1 and 10.')
        print('The first person to reach 100 is the winner.')
        print("Have fun, and let's get started!")
        totalNumber = 0
        while True:
            while totalNumber < 100:
                numberOne = input(oneName + ', give me a number between 1 and 10.')  # I don't know how to limit the range though
                numberOne = int(numberOne)
                totalNumber += numberOne
                print("Got it, " + oneName + "! Below is the total right now:")
                print(totalNumber)
                break
            while totalNumber < 100:
                numberTwo = input(twoName + ', give me a number between 1 and 10.')
                numberTwo = int(numberTwo)
                totalNumber += numberTwo
                print("Got it, " + twoName + "! Below is the total right now:")
                print(totalNumber)
            break
```

After all these codes, when we run the game, players can input numbers until the total reaches the number 100. However, I don't know how to make the game announce the winner. Like, keep track of the players' progress. If anyone can help, that would be great! Also, if you can help me out in fixing my problems in the code, that would be a huge help! Thank you :)

Comment: if totalNumber>=100
     print(oneName+"you are the winner")
write this line to your both while loops

Comment: keep a tuple ```(playername, progress)``` for each player in a list.

Comment: Why have a while loop if you run only for 1 iteration? You want an `if` instead.

Comment: Aah yes thanks Tanuj Yadav I solved it because of your help, thanks :) Also thanks everyone for helping me out, too :D

Comment: You might consider deleting the question, as it's (in its current form) unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint. Use `dict` in python. 
for example :

```
d = {'one' = 0,'two' = 0}
```

Increment `key` value each time and check if it reaches to `100`.

Hope you get it.

Comment: It is key value pair data structure. so you can have one dict object having two keys and those two keys can hold two different values. you can access these values using their keys. just search dictionary in python, you wil get idea.